# setting a link on a while loop php

Tags: php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mailtbl WHERE fromuser = '$adminsess' AND sent = '1'");

echo "To Subject Date View message";

while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $mid = $fetch['mid'];
    $to = $fetch['touser'];
    $subject2 = $fetch['subject'];
    $message2 = $fetch['message'];
    $date2 = $fetch['datesent'];
    $rand = $fetch['rand'];
    $view = "<a href = 'messages.php?mode=".$sent."&view=".$rand."'>View message</a>";

    echo "$to$subject2$date2$view";

}

echo "</table>";

if (isset($view)) {

    $viewget = $_GET['view'];

    if ($viewget== $rand) {

        echo "hi";
        echo "$message2";

    } 
}
```

The `$view` there suppose to open the content of each message. The main problem is, if I have multiple values in the table, after clicking the link in each row in the table, the only link that is functioning is in the last row. The previous rows in the table with links doesn't show the content of the message (which is echo "hi" & echo "$message2";).
What exactly is wrong with my code? thanks.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code so that it's readable, then highlight all the code in your question and press the code button (`{}`).

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code AlienWebguy. I don't know how to fix code structure here in StackOverflow. Can someone please answer my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @glov3 When you ask / answer a question, there's a big orange box with a question mark in it to the right and above the text area. That's the editor help

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing some of the excessive, uneven indenting in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to display the message is outside the `while` loop. If you want it to run for every message, then put it in the loop that is iterating over every message.

Comment: As you can see, the $message2 came from the while loop. The only problem is that, the last row is the only values that is showing the message. The if (isset($view) will trigger if the user clicked the link ($view).

Comment: Right. You need to move that code to within the loop. After the loop is over, the variables have the last value they took on, which was during the last iteration of the loop over the last row. If you want to compare every message to `$_GET['view']` to see if it should be shown, put the code in the loop.

Comment: I get it! I'll just have to fix it, but it's working now! Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Another question, is it possible to remove the table list after clicking the link? ($view) The message should only be shown, not with the table

Comment: Yes, with JavaScript. Create a `onclick` handler on the link that changes the table's CSS `display` property to `none`.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for that. The website as-is is created via PHP, so simply implement that logic in PHP. Just because you don't want to transmit the table even though you never show it provided JavaScript is enabled in the webbrowser.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `$rand` is not set inside the `isset($view)` check. `$rand` still contains the last value from the `while` loop above, so only the last `$viewget`/`$rand` will work.

My guess is that `messages.php` shows all available messages (the message list) and if clicked on one message, the message list and that selected message.

So first, before the `while` loop, you fetch the message identifier of the message to be shown:

```
$ViewRequested = isset($_GET['view']) ? $_GET['view'] : -1;
$ViewRequestedData = NULL;
```

Next, inside the `while` loop, you check if the user is allowed to view the selected message, and remember the record:

```
if ($rand == $ViewRequested) {
    $ViewRequestedData = $fetch;
}
```

Finally, after the `while` loop, you check whether there is a valid message requested:

```
if (is_array($ViewRequestedData) {
    echo $ViewRequestedData['message2'];
}
```